# Creating an array that shows Frequency + Location of individual values

Tags: google-sheets

I have an array filled with letters that occur in a particular order. The length of each row varies AND where the row starts also varies.

I need a formula that searches each row, counts each letter and where they begin, respective to each string of letters. Then organizes that information into an array.

For example:

This string of letters:

Phrase 1:  A D E A A F G

Would generate this output:

[image: ARRAY WITH COUNTS]

Because "A" shows up in the 1st, 4th, and 5th positions in this row.

This will be repeated for around 700 rows.

Here is a copy of a sheet for your review.

[GOOGLE SHEET THAT YOU CAN EDIT](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cZOg3ZhVt1Va_QKxcE6gS-82adVD-ept4h-KzLM5m-k/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: @pnuts Sorry, the Phrase 1 string had a typo, it is now fixed. I should note that each of the letters of that string is in it's own cell.

Comment: @pnuts correct. each phrase can use all letters, and start in different positions. I'm interested in the position of each letter relative to itself not the column

Comment: Correct, and I have a solution that does just that, but was curious if there was a way to avoid creating a 'helper' array

Comment: do you still need a solution for this?